# Meta_Search Rails - Search my Model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have a `User` class whose model is as below. I want to be able to use meta_search to search for a user by fullName, (i.e. `John Smith` rather than `John` or `Smith` (in separate fields)).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  search_methods :fullName

  def fullName
    firstName + " " + lastName
  end
end
```

And in my view:

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => users_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :fullName %> <%= f.text_field :fullName_equals %>
  <%= f.submit "Search Users" %>
<% end %>
```

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search) I should be able to use this, but it keeps raising an Exception:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#index

undefined method `fullName' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x#####>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add `attr_accessor :full_name` to your model.